# How to show for $Y\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ we have $\dim C(Y)=\dim Y+1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

I am looking at a problem in Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* book. (Chapter $1$, Section $2$, $10$th problem) I am stating it as it is given in the book.

> Let $Y\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a nonempty algebraic set, and let $\theta :\mathbb{A}^{n+1}\setminus\{(0,\ldots,0)\} \to \mathbb{P}^n$ be the map which sends the point with affine coordinates $(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$ to the point with homogeneous coordinates $(a_0,\ldots,a_n).$ We define the affine cone over $Y$ to be $C(Y)=\theta^{-1}(Y)\cup \{(0,\ldots,0)\}.$
>
> (a) Show that $C(Y)$ is an algebraic set in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1},$ whose ideal is equal to $I(Y),$ considered as an ordinary ideal in $K[x_0,\ldots,x_n].$
>
> (b) $C(Y)$ is irreducible iff $Y$ is.
>
> (c) $\dim C(Y)=\dim Y+1.$

I got stuck at part (c), while part (a) and part (b) follows from the following observation

> If $\mathfrak{a}$ is a homogeneous ideal in $K[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ with $Z_{\mathbb{P}^n}(\mathfrak{a})\neq\emptyset,$ then $Z_{\mathbb{A}^{n+1}}(\mathfrak{a})=\theta^{-1}(Z_{\mathbb{P}^n}(\mathfrak{a}))\cup \{0,\ldots,0\}$.

Part (c) is clear when $Y$ is a projective variety since $\dim C(Y)=\dim K[x_0,\ldots,x_n]/I(Y)=\dim Y+1.$

My question is what happens if $Y$ is just projective algebraic set not necessarily irreducible ?

Help me. Many thanks.

Comment: One idea: dimension of a space is the supremum of dimensions of its irreducible components. By breaking your algebraic set into irreducibles you may be able to reduce to the case of an algebraic variety.

Comment: Since I am following Hartshornes book  I want to apply his definition as the supremum of lengths of chain of irreducible closed set as dimension.

Comment: Andrew's suggestion uses the same definition, and is an extremely common tool.  If $X$ is irreducible contained in $Y_1 \cup Y_2$, where each $Y_i$ is irreducible, then $X$ is contained in either $Y_1$ or $Y_2$.  Therefore, the dimension of a space is the supremum of dimensions of its irreducible components.

Comment: I got it..thanks.