# Dimension of Closed Projective Scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation

My question concerns an argument in following former thread: 
[How to show for $Y\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ we have $\dim C(Y)=\dim Y+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2124368/how-to-show-for-y-subset-mathbbpn-we-have-dim-cy-dim-y1?rq=1)

One considers here a problem in Hartshorne's "Algebraic Geometry" . (Chapter $1$, Section $2$, $10$th problem):

Let $Y\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a nonempty algebraic set, and let $\theta :\mathbb{A}^{n+1}\setminus\{(0,\ldots,0)\} \to \mathbb{P}^n$ be the map which sends the point with affine coordinates $(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$ to the point with homogeneous coordinates $(a_0,\ldots,a_n).$ We define the affine cone over $Y$ to be $C(Y)=\theta^{-1}(Y)\cup \{(0,\ldots,0)\}.$

Two qestions:

1. In the thread the autor states that the statement

c) $\dim C(Y)=\dim Y+1.$

should be clear by the argument that

$$\dim C(Y)=\dim K[x_0,\ldots,x_n]/I(Y)=\dim Y+1.$$

I don't see why $\dim K[x_0,\ldots,x_n]/I(Y)=\dim Y+1.$ holds.

2. What means the notation $Z_{\mathbb{P}^n}(\mathfrak{a})$ for an ideal $\mathfrak{a}$?

Comment: Have you tried anything on the dimension question? Do you see why it holds for the case of a point or the whole space in $\Bbb P^n$? For the notational question, this appears to be specifying that the writer is taking the zero locus of $\mathfrak{a}$ inside $\Bbb P^n$. This is useful since the same ideal corresponds to two geometric objects: $Y$ and the cone on $Y$.

Comment: @KReiser: For the both special cases it seems indeed clear: For $Y= \{*\}$ we have $dim(Y) =0$ and since $Y$ then corresponds to a closed point, $I(Y)$ is a maximal ideal. Futhermore, if $Y =\mathbb{P}^n$, $I(Y)$ is the zero ideal and the statement also holds since $\dim \mathbb{P}^n$=n. The problem is the general case. By Hilbert's BT $I(Y) = (f_1, ..., f_n)$ finitely generated, but does it help here to reduce the problem?

Comment: Dig in to the easy cases: use the definition of dimension as supremum of length of certain chains. What ideal is present in $\Bbb A^n$ that isn't present in $\Bbb P^n$? Do you see how to use this? Alternatively, use other easy examples: can you handle a line in $\Bbb P^n$ or a hyperplane?

Comment: @KReiser: Ah, you mean the "irrelevant" ideal $(x_0,..., x_n)$. This is neglected in the prime ideal chain you mentioned above in the projective case. So this has to be added by the $1$, because one knows that in affine case $Y = \dim K[x_0,\ldots,x_n]/I(Y)$ holds (so for $Y \subset \mathbb{A}^n$. Did you had this in mind?

Comment: Yes, this is the solution to the problem. I'd highly recommend working through some examples _before_ asking an MSE question next time.